# Writing into a NumPy memmap still loads into RAM memory

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I'm testing NumPy's memmap through IPython Notebook, with the following code

```
Ymap = np.memmap('Y.dat', dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(5e6, 4e4))
```

As you can see, `Ymap`'s shape is pretty large. I'm trying to fill up `Ymap` like a sparse matrix. I'm not using `scipy.sparse` matrices because I will eventually need to dot-product it with another dense matrix, which will definitely not fit into memory.

Anyways, I'm performing a very long series of indexing operations:

```
Ymap = np.memmap('Y.dat', dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(5e6, 4e4))
with open("somefile.txt", 'rb') as somefile:
    for i in xrange(5e6):
        # Read a line
        line = somefile.readline()
        # For each token in the line, lookup its j value
        # Assign the value 1.0 to Ymap[i,j]
        for token in line.split():
            j = some_dictionary[token]
            Ymap[i,j] = 1.0
```

These operations somehow quickly eat up my RAM. I thought mem-mapping was basically an out-of-core `numpy.ndarray`. Am I mistaken? Why is my memory usage sky-rocketing like crazy?

Comment: Why would you _want_ it to not use memory if it's available? It'll be orders of magnitude slower that way, and if you're not using the memory for anything else, you get no benefit for that cost. In the rare cases where you know more about memory needs than the OS can guess (e.g., you have a big hunk of stuff you haven't touched in a while, but are about to scan over N times in a row), you may need to `madvise`/`mprotect` or the Win32 equivalents manually, but otherwise, you shouldn't be worrying about it at all. Quickly eating up your RAM is the right thing to do, so be happy.

Comment: Take a look at pytables, it might be a good tool here

Comment: I don't think PyTables has support for dot-products, which was why I was looking into memmap.

Comment: pytables wont support calculating dot products of huge matrixes with a quick convenience function. But implementing the dot product algorithm manually should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: @richizy: dot products with very sparse mmap'd arrays will probably be orders of magnitude slower than with `scipy.sparse.cs{c,r}_matrix`. Dense matrix multiplication doesn't know a priori where the zeros are and will loop over all the elements.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A (non-anonymous) `mmap` is a link between a file and RAM that, roughly, guarantees that when RAM of the `mmap` is full, data will be paged to the given file instead of to the swap disk/file, and when you `msync` or `munmap` it, the whole region of RAM gets written out to the file. Operating systems typically follow a lazy strategy wrt. disk accesses (or eager wrt. RAM): data will remain in memory as long as it fits. This means a process with large mmaps will eat up as much RAM as it can/needs before spilling over the rest to disk.

So you're right that an `np.memmap` array is an out-of-core array, but it is one that will grab as much RAM cache as it can.

Comment: So memmap is basically useless.

Comment: @agemO, The goal isn't to minimize RAM usage.  It works great with `.npy` files larger than ram, or large files you only need to access a few elements of without loading the entire file from disk.

Comment: 'The goal isn't to minimize RAM usage' -> Then I think: 'Memory-mapped files are used for accessing small segments of large files on disk, without reading the entire file into memory.' is really misleading. This is exactly the kind of sentences you can read about h5py or some of pandas loading functions, but in these cases it really means 'let's read the whole file chunks by chunks!'

Answer (score 7):

As [the docs say](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html):

> Memory-mapped files are used for accessing small segments of large files on disk, without reading the entire file into memory.

There's no true magic in computers ;-)  If you access very little of a giant array, a memmap gimmick will require very little RAM; if you access very much of a giant array, a memmap gimmick will require very much RAM.

One workaround that may or may not be helpful in your specific code:  create new mmap objects periodically (and get rid of old ones), at logical points in your workflow.  Then the amount of RAM needed should be roughly proportional to the number of array items you touch between such steps.  Against that, it takes time to create and destroy new mmap objects.  So it's a balancing act.

Comment: This is a useful solution to those like me who are memory limited and only need Order(30ms) delays between reads from the disk.