# Flushing memmap completely to disk

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn

Is there a way to completely flush memmap from memory in Python and somehow just store a pointer? I notice `memmap_object.flush()` and `del memmap_object` have different effects.

Complete Code:

```
temp_train_data=X_train[1000:]
temp_labels=y[1000:] 
out = np.empty((200001, 3504), np.int64)
for index,row in enumerate(temp_train_data):
    actual_index=index+1000
    data=X_train[actual_index-1000:actual_index+1].ravel()
    __,cd_i=pywt.dwt(data,'haar')
    out[index] = cd_i
out.flush()
pca_obj=IncrementalPCA()
clf = pca_obj.fit(out)
```

Edit 1:(@stark suggestion)
Main problems relating to the question:

1. `clf = pca_obj.fit(out)` trashes my RAM.
2. I want more RAM freed up so I can increase the batch-size of iterative PCA.

Comment: Using del  will flush and delete the object, flush will obviously flush

Comment: How memory should the object occupy? Does it act as a pointer to the file? Sorry if the questions are naive, I am new to python and numpy.

Comment: memap returns an array like object,  if you del the object you won't be able to use it again

Comment: What size does the array occupy in memory. I keen to just have a pointer to the memmap on disk to save my memory. And later pass this to IncrementalPCA can batch process, saving my RAM from crashing.

Comment: Mmap allocates virtual memory, not physical memory.   The OS manages how much physical memory is in use.  RAM will not "crash"  unless you are doing ACCESS_COPY but you may run into process limits on your virtual address space.

Comment: @stark Thanks for the comment! What do you suggest is the way to free up all the RAM and use it for `clf = pca_obj.fit(out)`.

Comment: Why do you need to do anything?  If you are getting an error you should have posted it.

Comment: Sorry should have posted before: 1.) `clf = pca_obj.fit(out)` trashes my RAM. 2.) I want more RAM freed up so I can increase the batch-size of iterative PCA.

Comment: You need to publish Tracebacks, rather than just saying "my RAM is crashing".  Because you're not just showing the traceback and asking why am I getting a `MemoryError`, your questions have the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/261369). In this question, for instance, you ask about `memmap` but have no `memmap` in the code you post here. I think this is basically a dupicate of [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32242911/using-memmap-files-for-batch-processing), too.